# How to create array of pointers using double pointers?

Tags: c++

```
char* rec1= "mailid1@xxx.com";
char* rec2= "mailid2@xxx.com";

char** rec ;
```

I need to make `char** rec` points to `rec1` and `rec2` and I should be able to access the `rec1` and `rec2` elements from rec by using `rec[0]` and `rec[1]` .

How to achieve it?

Comment: `char* rec1 = "mailid1@xxx.com";` is illegal in C++ today. You require a `const`

Comment: @WhiZTiM - Sadly you need to compile in the equivalent of pedantic-errors mode to actually have that flagged.

Comment: Try `std::vector<std::string> rec = {"mailid1@xxx.com", "mailid2@xxx.com"};`.

Comment: @StoryTeller, I just experimented that with various compilers. And I am surprised compilers still provide it as a *default* extension, (and I am certian this stuff attracts UB bugs).... Anyway, maybe, enforcing it by default breaks a ton of code out there...

Comment: @WhiZTiM - That's the likely reason. Although one would think that 20 or so years is enough time to fix such smelly code...

Comment: @StoryTeller & WhiZTiM Both g++ and clang++ have warned of the conversion since quite a long time (since always? I don't know) without specifying any compilation options explicitly. It's clarifying to understand that the conversion used to be well formed until C++11, so until then standard conforming compilers weren't even allowed to treat it as an error (but still warned of course, because the conversion was deprecated since the first version of the standard). Since C++11, decision to support the conversion as an extension is surely because of backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you're looking for.

```
const char *rec1 = "mailid1@xxx.com";
const char *rec2 = "mailid2@xxx.com";

const char *rec[] = {rec1, rec2};

std::cout << rec[1];
```

- `"mailid1@xxx.com"` on its own is of type `const char[16]` which decays to `const char *`. Note that it shouldn't be assigned to a `char *` since those chars are read-only.
- `const char *rec[]` is an array type of `const char *`. Also `{rec1, rec2}` is an initializer for array types.